# Narrow container of generic by generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have a generic container like this

```
export interface A {
 type: 'A',
 value: string
}

export interface B {
 type: 'B',
 value: number
}

export interface Container<T> {
  data: T
}

export type ContainerOfAB = Container<A | B>
```

Is it possible to narrow the type of a `ContainerOfAB` by the value of its data object? For example:

```
export interface A {
 type: 'A',
 value: string
}

export interface B {
 type: 'B',
 value: number
}

export interface Container<T> {
  data: T
}

export type ContainerOfAB = Container<A | B>

export function detect(item: ContainerOfAB) {
  switch(item.data.type) {
    case 'A':
      takesGenericA(item) // fails
      break;
     case 'B':
      takesGenericB(item) // fails
      break;
  }
}

function takesGenericA(e: Container<A>) {

}

function takesGenericB(e: Container<B>) {

}
```

It seems that its not able to narrow the container's inner value enough to pass to another method, even though the switch does work?

This example gives the following error to either of the invocations of the narrowed type

```
Argument of type 'ContainerOfAB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Container<B>'.
  Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"B"'.(2345)
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8BYAKDhgE8xgAuOAcn0YBpy4A3TAGwFd6cAM4woyAObkAvuXKhIsRCjRZccAELEO1Wg0bq2Hbv0FI+AWwBGaabLLzo8ZKgw48AYQgpMyNAB4AFQA+LQo4ABNMGEwGANsyOXBHShoPL2jfKAB5dHxNAF44T29Mv0IAHw0guwdFdD4kbBgELwjgVCaACgRUcwZijKQ0HLyASlC4YQB3HuwAC27egDpI6KWdYHHSMMnsTCE8ZkY6Dkmz6IBrYCEAcWAhsWx8ReBzUdOzuEsoYEwLgG4Prt9ocDCcdp9KH9rncHghsOoXm8gZ9vr8AacZGQseR6o1mq1LjD7mh4c9BAMfA8ykEtnYcWQ8U0WkgoVdbiTHoiKekqf51LTQtIgA)

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of whatever problem you're facing is?  Is there an error somewhere?  Or show some code that would error where you don't want it to (or the reverse)?

Comment: Your example does what you want and correctly narrows the type ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8BYAKDhgE8xgAuOAcn0YBpy4A3TAGwFd6cAM4woyAObkAvuXKhIsRCjRZccAELEO1Wg0bq2Hbv0FI+AWwBGaabLLzo8ZKgw48AYQgpMyNAB4AFQA+LQo4ABNMGEwGANsyOXBHShoPL2jfKAB5dHxNAF44T29Mv0IAHw0guwdFdD4kbBgELwjgVCaACgRUcwZijKQ0HLyASlC4YQB3HuwAC27egDpI6KWdYHHSMMm4bEwhPGZGBg5d86h2vigkRGXVzCXjATPd-cOmAzpX87hLmGutx6wHMKyij2ewDOMjIUiAA)). You may want to add more detail here to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JacobGillespie if you add one more level of [indirection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8BYAKDhgE8xgAuOAcn0YBpy4A3TAGwFd6cAM4woyAObkAvuXKhIsRCjRZccAELEO1Wg0bq2Hbv0FI+AWwBGaabLLzo8ZKgw48AYQgpMyNAB4AFQA+LQo4ABNMGEwGANsyOXBHShoPL2jfKAB5dHxNAF44T29Mv0IAHw0guwdFdD4kbBgELwjgVCaACgRUcwZijKQ0HLyASlC4YQB3HuwAC27egDpI6KWdYHHSMMnsTCE8ZkY6Dkmz6IBrYCEAcWAhsWx8ReBzUdOzuEsoYEwLgG4Prt9ocDCcdp9KH9rncHghsOoXm8gZ9vr8AacZGQseR6o1mq1LjD7mh4c9BAMfA8ykEtnYcWQ8U0WkgoVdbiTHoiKekqf51LTQtIgA) it breaks.  This is really the crux of my question

Comment: Ah, yes so in that case you have narrowed `item.data` with the switch statement, but not `item` itself ([for example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8BYAKDhgE8xgAuOAcn0YBpy4A3TAGwFd6cAM4woyAObkAvuXKhIsRCjRZccAELEO1Wg0bq2Hbv0FI+AWwBGaabLLzo8ZKgw48AYQgpMyNAB4AFQA+LQo4ABNMGEwGANsyOXBHShoPL2jfKAB5dHxNAF44T29Mv0IAHw0guwdFdD4kbBgELwjgVCaACgRUcwZijKQ0HLyASlC4YQB3HuwAC27egDpI6KWdYHHSMMnsTCE8ZkY6Dkmz6IBrYCEAcWAhsWx8TqIIqJjEZdXMOClR07OcEsUGAmAuAG4Abt9ocDCcdoDKGDrncHghsOoXt8GD1gOYVu9fv8EYDgaCIacZGQqeR6o1mq1Lij7mh0c9BAMfA8ykEtnYaWQ6U0WkgkVdbizHpiOekuf51LzQtIgA))

Comment: My understanding is that this distinction between narrowing the property and its container is partially due to safety reasons (you're not necessarily guaranteed to get the same `data` from `item.data` later in the code) and partially a limitation of the type checker.

Comment: @JacobGillespie yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to reconstruct the object. I can spread the object  back but it just seems silly to have to do `takesThing({... event, data: event.data})`